# How to make my PC non pingable for other local network PCs?

Tags: windows, networking, configuration, network-programming, ping

*First*
Need to know if that possible
To make my PC non pingable for other local network PCs ??

If **YES** ... **HOW**?
IF **NO** ... **WHY**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the command prompt **as administrator**:

To block the pings, use this command:

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”ICMP V4″ protocol=icmpv4:any,any dir=in action=block

To allow the ping again, use this command:

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”ICMP V4″ protocol=icmpv4:any,any dir=in action=allow

What this does is that it adds an exception/acceptance for the ICMP into Windows native firewall.

If that does not work, do it manually. There's a guide: http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7